# Simple.Data Insert Object - List initializers must contain at least one initializer

Tags: simple.data

When I run the following code :

```
        var db = Database.Open();
        var contact = new Contact() {FirstName = "Mark", LastName = "Rendle"} ;
        db.Contacts.Insert(contact);
```

I get an error :

*List initializers must contain at least one initializer*

Stack Trace : 
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ListInit(NewExpression newExpression, IEnumerable`1 initializers)
   at Simple.Data.Extensions.ObjectEx.MakeToDictionaryFunc(Type type)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Simple.Data.Extensions.ObjectEx.ObjectToDictionary(Object obj)
   at Simple.Data.Commands.InsertCommand.InsertEntity(Object entity, DataStrategy dataStrategy, String tableName, ErrorCallback onError, Boolean resultRequired)
   at Simple.Data.Commands.InsertCommand.DoInsert(InvokeMemberBinder binder, Object[] args, DataStrategy dataStrategy, String tableName)
   at Simple.Data.Commands.InsertCommand.Execute(DataStrategy dataStrategy, DynamicTable table, InvokeMemberBinder binder, Object[] args)
   at Simple.Data.DynamicTable.TryInvokeMember(InvokeMemberBinder binder, Object[] args, Object& result)
   at Simple.Data.ObjectReference.TryInvokeMember(InvokeMemberBinder binder, Object[] args, Object& result)
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Object )
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid2[T0,T1](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
   at ProjectXBaseDataImporter.DataSaver.PersistContacts(IEnumerable`1 contactsx) in c:\Code\XXX\ProjectXBaseDataImporter\ProjectXBaseDataImporter\CSVImporter.cs:line 54
   at ProjectXBaseDataImporter.DataImporter.Import[T](String filePath) in c:\Code\XXX\ProjectXBaseDataImporter\ProjectXBaseDataImporter\CSVImporter.cs:line 77
   at ProjectXBaseDataImporter.DataImporter_Test.Import() in c:\Code\XXX\ProjectXBaseDataImporter\ProjectXBaseDataImporter\CSVImporter_Test.cs:line 32

Comment: Any chance of a stack trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error on my part.

Another Library I am using requires classes to have fields opposed to properties.
I was coding against the fields not properties.

Comment: You should accept this as your answer, for the benefit of others.